# How do I increases the number of guesses?

Tags: python

I can get everything to work on this code, except when I play the game the result always says it took me 4 guesses. How do I properly increase the number of guesses and relay that back to the player?

```
import random
n = random.randint(1, 75)
print "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 75. "
guess = int(raw_input("What's your guess?: "))
while guess != n:
  guesses_taken = 1
  if guess == n:
    break
  if guess < n:
    print "Your guess was too low"
    guess = int(raw_input("Try again:"))
    guesses_taken += guesses_taken
  elif guess > n:
    print "Your guess was too high"
    guess = int(raw_input("Try again:"))
    guesses_taken += guesses_taken
if guess == n:
  guesses_taken += guesses_taken
  guesses_taken = str(guesses_taken)
  print "Good job! It took you " + guesses_taken + " guesses to get it right!"
```

Comment: Unrelated tip: try to switch to Python 3, as Python 2 isn't longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

as @[PNX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12903729/pnx) stated, the guesses taken should be outside of the loop, but you're also doing
`guesses_taken += guesses_taken`
What you're doing when you do this statement is:

```py
guesses_taken = guesses_taken + guesses_taken
```

but what you should be doing is :

```py
guesses_taken = guesses_taken + 1
```

or

```py
guesses_taken += 1
```

The full code would then be:

```py
import random
n = random.randint(1, 75)
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 75. ")
guess = int(input("What's your guess?: "))
guesses_taken = 1
while guess != n:
  if guess == n:
    break
  if guess < n:
    print("Your guess was too low")
    guess = int(input("Try again:"))
    guesses_taken += 1
  elif guess > n:
    print("Your guess was too high")
    guess = int(input("Try again:"))
    guesses_taken += 1
if guess == n:
  guesses_taken = str(guesses_taken)
  print("Good job! It took you " + guesses_taken + " guesses to get it right!")
```

I also translated this code to Python 3 because I have no way to run Python 2. You will have to convert back if you still want to use Python 2